# How does -fsanitize=leak affect runtime performance?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, memory-leaks, address-sanitizer

Modern C/C++ compilers including `g++`, `clang` supports `AddressSanitizerLeakSanitizer` function by appending `-fsanitize=leak` to compiler / linker flags and it is very useful for finding potential memory leaks before releasing C++ project.

I wonder if there is performance impact when the option is enabled compared to the same program without it.
If there is, how does the option affects runtime performance (e.g. ~10x slower than without the option).
I could not find an official document that mentioned the topic.

Comment: Do a performance benchmark to see what the impact is.

Comment: Not the sort of thing I would document. Benchmarking code built to detect errors is almost always counter productive because it doesn't represent reality all that well.

Comment: There are no numbers because the performance depends heavily on the ratio of the affected functions and the rest of your program. As @Barmar suggests, you need to benchmark **your** application.

Comment: Why do you care about the performance impact, anyway? You're not planning on enabling this in production, are you?

Comment: Are you asking about _Leak_ or _Address_ sanitizer? Your title suggest the former but question text ask about the latter... (the answer will be different depending on which one you need)

Comment: Address sanitizer is [documented](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer) to have an average slowdown of ~2x. But since the stand-alone leak sanitizer [doesn't need compile-time instrumentation](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerLeakSanitizer#stand-alone-mode), I would expect it to be a lot faster.